# What's the difference between にしたら and の上では

Tags: grammar

There has been a post for the difference between にしたら and として and にとって, but I haven't been able to find anything about the phrase の上では which also supposedly means "from the viewpoint of" or "according to" 
So what's the difference here?

Comment: Do you have example sentences?

Answer (score 1):

(person) にしたら means "from the viewpoint of (person)" in the sense that you would think/feel that way if you were in his/her position.

の上では doesn't take person to begin with and doesn't mean that. It takes objects like theory, imagination, law, or document, and means "in theory", "in imagination", "in law" and "as long as the document says" respectively, as opposed to reality.